# Update column value using Grouping in Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, grouping

I'm trying to do a simple automation using Grouping in Pandas for a sample dataframe like below. Appreciate any help.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'C1':['A','A','B','B'], 'C2':['A1','A2','B1','B2']})
```

[image]

Expected Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate expected output ? Why do you want that ? According to code the output is correct

Comment: I just want the first value of every group to be added to C2 column. Here, A and B are two groups and I want these values to be added to C2 in every group

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there is a more pythonic way to sort the data frames added by the pandas series. I am sure you will get some answers from advanced users with my answers.

```
a = pd.Series(['A','A'], index=df.columns, name=4)
b = pd.Series(['B','B'], index=df.columns, name=5)
df = df.append(a)
df = df.append(b)
df.sort_values('C2', ascending=True, inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
df
    C1  C2
0   A   A
1   A   A1
2   A   A2
3   B   B
4   B   B1
5   B   B2
```

Comment: Hi, this works only with the given input. But, doesn't provide the required output when bulk of groups & values are given as input.

Comment: 'A' can be replaced by `df['C1'].unique()[0]'`? `name=4` would be replaced by `len(df)+1`.